# Print from SqlDataReader urls

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im new to C#, Im required to print the urls of the videos in my database as urls that redirect to that link. Im printing them as strings, any ideas how to make them redirect to the actual links

```
if (rdr3.Read()) {
    while (rdr3.Read())
    {
        string video = rdr3.GetString(rdr3.GetOrdinal("video"));

        Label lbl_video = new Label();
        lbl_video.Text = "Video url:  " + video;
        form1.Controls.Add(lbl_video);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
HyperLink VideoLink = new HyperLink();
VideoLink.NavigateUrl = video;
VideoLink.Text = "Click Me!";
```

Of course, you'll want to replace "Click Me!" with something meaningful like the name of the video.